# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. Suggest me the solution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2020.3.4f1, creating android AR face tracking app using AR Foundation, ARCore and ARkitFace Tracking. When i try build apk that time getting that error.

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
> Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.0/gradle-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.0/gradle-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.6.0/builder-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.6.0/builder-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.6.0/crash-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.6.0/crash-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.6.0/lint-gradle-api-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.6.0/lint-gradle-api-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.6.0/gradle-api-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.6.0/gradle-api-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.6.0/databinding-compiler-common-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.6.0/databinding-compiler-common-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.6.0/manifest-merger-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.6.0/manifest-merger-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.6.0/sdk-common-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.6.0/sdk-common-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.6.0/builder-test-api-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.6.0/builder-test-api-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.6.0/ddmlib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.6.0/ddmlib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download signflinger.jar (com.android:signflinger:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/3.6.0/signflinger-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/3.6.0/signflinger-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download zipflinger.jar (com.android:zipflinger:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/3.6.0/zipflinger-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/3.6.0/zipflinger-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.6.0/tracker-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.6.0/tracker-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.6.0/sdklib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.6.0/sdklib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.6.0/layoutlib-api-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.6.0/layoutlib-api-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.6.0/dvlib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.6.0/dvlib-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.6.0/repository-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.6.0/repository-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.6.0/shared-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.6.0/shared-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.6.0/common-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.6.0/common-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta08)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta08/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta08.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta08/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta08.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.10.3)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.10.3/bundletool-0.10.3.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.10.3/bundletool-0.10.3.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta08)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta08/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta08.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta08/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta08.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.6.0/protos-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.6.0/protos-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.4.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.4.0/aapt2-proto-0.4.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.4.0/aapt2-proto-0.4.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.6.0/builder-model-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.6.0/builder-model-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.6.0/apkzlib-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.6.0/apkzlib-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.6.0/apksig-3.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.6.0/apksig-3.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.6.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.6.0/annotations-26.6.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.6.0/annotations-26.6.0.jar'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not download databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:

Comment: Please see my answer below, next time please look up the correct error message and name the title of the question with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a certificate error from Java, it cannot validate HTTPS certificate when attempting to download .jar dependencies, please try the following:

1. Make sure you have imported the public certificate of the target instance into the truststore according to the Connecting to SSL Services instructions.
2. Make sure any certificates have been imported into the correct truststore; you may have multiple JRE/JDKs. Try reinstalling Java for this.
3. Check to see that the correct truststore is in use. If -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore has been configured, it will override the location of the default truststore, which will need to be checked.
4. If this error results while integrating with an LDAP server over LDAPS and there is more than one LDAP server, then deselect the Follow referrals option within the LDAP user directory configuration per Connecting to and LDAP Directory.  Optionally, import the SSL certificates from the other LDAP servers into the Confluence truststore.
5. Check if your Anti Virus tool has "SSL Scanning" blocking SSL/TLS. If it does, disable this feature or set exceptions for the target addresses (check the product documentation to see if this is possible.) If connecting to a mail server, such as Exchange, ensure authentication allows plain text.
6. Verify that the target server is configured to serve SSL correctly. This can be done with the SSL Server Test tool. If all else fails, your truststore might be out of date. Upgrade Java to the latest version supported by your application.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-error-779355358.html